# SQL Server: hide column that is part of SELECT clause, and used in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-update

*(Updated to clarify based on feedback in comments)*

I am using `SELECT` to query a number of columns.

One of these columns (`[Betaling (brutto)]`) is used in an `UPDATE` statement to calculate a second column.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetTrips]
    @trips udtTripsPerMonth readonly

AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.tblTripsPerMonth(*list of columns*)

        SELECT  [KjøretøyID], 
                MAX(SUBSTRING([År], 7, 4)), 
                MAX(SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2)), 
                SUM([Betaling (brutto)]) AS [Betaling (brutto)], 
                SUM([Betaling (netto)]) AS [Betaling (netto)], 
                SUM([Bestillingsgebyr (netto)]) AS [Bestillingsgebyr (netto)], 
                SUM([Betalingsgebyr (netto)]) AS [Betalingsgebyr (netto)],
                VARP([OppdragsMVAkode]),
                MAX(CONCAT(LøyvehaverFakturaID, 
                    + 'UF-' + SUBSTRING([År], 9, 2) 
                    + SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2))), 
                SUM([Oppdragsgebyr (netto)]) AS [Oppdragsgebyr (netto)], 
                VARP([OppdragsgebyrMVAkode]), 
                MAX(CONCAT([RidelRegionFakturaID], 
                    + 'UF-' + SUBSTRING([År], 9, 2) 
                    + SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2)))

            FROM @trips
                                
            GROUP BY [KjøretøyID]
            ORDER BY [KjøretøyID]
                    
    UPDATE tblTripsPerMonth
    SET [Oppdragsgebyr (netto)] = (

        SELECT [Betaling (brutto)] * 8 / 100
    );  
END
```

This is the results it gives me:

[image: query results]

How can I hide `[Betaling (brutto)]` from the query results?

Comment: You have 2 completely separate SQL statements. Just remove the columns you don't to include in your SELECT statement.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  `UPDATE` doesn't return a result set, so your question is unclear.

Comment: Please see my updated question, thanks!

Comment: Your question is still far from clear. You have two update statements, the second looks like a syntax error - updates don't return any results so what are the results you are referring to?

Comment: the query result is select and I don't see an select in your stored procedure. If you don't want a column in the result set, simply skip that in the SELECT

Comment: You have no `SELECT`, only an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and neither of these should return a resultset. If you are just doing `SELECT *` then specify the columns explicitly. Side notes: The `UPDATE` could simply be `[Oppdragsgebyr (netto)] = [Betaling (brutto)] * 8 / 100`. You could place that directly in the `INSERT` instead. Even better: scrap all that and use a computed column

Comment: I am really confused as to why people are saying they don't see a `SELECT` in my stored procedure.. haha.. It's right there.... (I am obviously not getting something..)

Comment: THere is nothing to be confused about. The word `select` appears twice; the first is as part of an `insert` statement, the second in a malformed `update` statement. *Neither* is a stand-alone statement that returns data to the client.

Comment: @stu thanks for commenting, but why does that matter in regards to what I'm asking in my question? And in what way is my `UPDATE` malformed? It does what I want it to (not being smart, genuinely curious and want to learn). My query returns the data I want it to return, I just want to hide one of the columns in the query results (after calculation has been done)

Comment: Malformed might be the wrong word - the `select` is unecessary since you're only updating rows in the same table you can reference the other column directly. It matters because your question refers to *results* - I think most people are expecting whatever this means to be the "results" from a data retrieval *select* statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you think about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetTrips]
    @trips udtTripsPerMonth readonly

AS
BEGIN
```

INSERT INTO dbo.tblTripsPerMonth([KjøretøyID], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [Bestillingsgebyr (netto)], [Betalingsgebyr (netto)], [OppdragsMVAkode], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [Oppdragsgebyr (netto)], [OppdragsgebyrMVAkode], [RidelRegionFakturaID])

```
    SELECT [KjøretøyID], [År], [Måned], [Betaling (brutto)], [Betaling (netto)], [Bestillingsgebyr (netto)], [Betalingsgebyr (netto)], 
    [OppdragsMVAkode], [LøyvehaverFakturaID], [Betaling (brutto)] * 8 / 100 AS [Oppdragsgebyr (netto)], [OppdragsgebyrMVAkode], [RidelRegionFakturaID]
    FROM 
    
    (SELECT [KjøretøyID], 
            MAX(SUBSTRING([År], 7, 4)), 
            MAX(SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2)), 
            SUM([Betaling (brutto)]) AS [Betaling (brutto)], 
            SUM([Betaling (netto)]) AS [Betaling (netto)], 
            SUM([Bestillingsgebyr (netto)]) AS [Bestillingsgebyr (netto)], 
            SUM([Betalingsgebyr (netto)]) AS [Betalingsgebyr (netto)],
            VARP([OppdragsMVAkode]),
            MAX(CONCAT(LøyvehaverFakturaID, 
                + 'UF-' + SUBSTRING([År], 9, 2) 
                + SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2))), 
            VARP([OppdragsgebyrMVAkode]), 
            MAX(CONCAT([RidelRegionFakturaID], 
                + 'UF-' + SUBSTRING([År], 9, 2) 
                + SUBSTRING([Måned], 4, 2)))

        FROM @trips AS o
        
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                    FROM tblTripsPerMonth i
                    INNER JOIN @trips o
                        ON i.KjøretøyID = o.KjøretøyID
                        AND i.[Betaling (netto)] = o.[Betaling (netto)]
                        AND i.LøyvehaverFakturaID = o.LøyvehaverFakturaID )
        
    GROUP BY [KjøretøyID]
    

    ) base;
END
```

Comment: Thanks @László Tóth, but this gave me an error message:
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
And a red squiggly under 'base', "No column was specific for column 9 of 'base'"
But all columns are present. Does it have to do with having to name aliases?

Comment: You can take the order by clause out of subquery. Under the ')base' row. Perhaps you can write base..

Comment: thanks, but that did not work for me. If I move it under the `)base` row, all my columns get `invalid column name` error message.

Comment: Could you share your tables here https://www.db-fiddle.com/?  Or could you post yout full sql statement and the error.

Comment: Appreciate that! Here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZKMD7uJMJeSNmcunJayew/4

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I know just sql not sql server, so I Can't test it. (fiddle I can choose just mysql).  By insert you can eliminate the ORDER BY. Because by select you have to order by to.